# Excel vba getElementsByClassName

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to scrape IPO date from crunchbase. 
Unfortunately I get Runtime Error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error”.
My goal is to save IPO date in A1 cell.

```
Sub GetIE()
  Dim IE As Object
  Dim URL As String
  Dim myValue As IHTMLElement
  URL = "https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/verastem"
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.Navigate URL
  Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
  Loop
  Set myValue = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("post_glass post_micro_glass")(0)
  Range("A1").Value = myValue
  Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: When I run this, the error occurs on stmt  Range("A1").Value = myValue.  Ergo, the prior stmt Set myValue failed to find the Element requested.  The code needs to "get..." a element that is there.  Please SHOW/DEMONSTRATE why you think that element is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find that class name in the html for that url. You can use the css selector I show below which can be scraped by xmlhttp and thus avoiding opening a browser

```
Option Explicit    
Public Sub GetDate()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Set html = New HTMLDocument                  '<  VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/verastem#section-overview", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = html.querySelectorAll(".field-type-date.ng-star-inserted").item(1).innerText
End Sub
```

If you don't want to use compound classes then you can also use

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = html.querySelectorAll("#section-ipo-stock-price .field-type-date").item(1).innerText
```

You can see the relevant html here:

[image]

Note the element has multiple (compound) classes

```
<span class="component--field-formatter field-type-date ng-star-inserted" title="Jan 27, 2012">Jan 27, 2012</span>
```

There are 3 classes `component--field-formatter` ; `field-type-date` and `ng-star-inserted`. I use two of these in combination in the first solution I give. Multiple classes is popular now-a-days due to the versatility it gives in page styling e.g. it allows overriding styles easily. You can read about css [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)* to understand this better.

More classes may mean the code is a little less robust as the ordering of classes may be changed and a class, or more, may be removed. This was raised by @SIM in a comment on an answer to another web-scraping question. Thus, I offer one solution with two of the classes used, and another solution with only one of the classes used.

---

Whilst you do get the same date for this page with simply:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = html.querySelector("#section-ipo-stock-price .field-type-date").innerText
```

I wouldn't want to assume that would always hold true as it grabs the date from the line where it says `"Their stock opened"`.

<sub>* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity</sub>

References:

1. [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)
2. [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)